# How do convert header values to row values in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I am trying to convert my header values into rows.
I converted my csv file into excel using Pentaho, when I Click preview, it looks like this:

[header to row value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJqqM.png)
What should I do to convert the header values to row values, the output should look like this:
[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68gXw.png)

Comment: ok, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a CSV file with more than 1000 entries that has no header. I converted this CSV to an Excel file using Excel output (ex. excelOutput1)
Now I have a file excelOutput1 with all the fields, and i only want to to extract certain fields from this, example the 1st and 4th row.
So output this to another excel Input where I specify the rows that I want. When I click preview, it shows like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJqqM.png
The picture displays all the rows that I want. And I was only able to get this once I check the Header checkbox.

Comment: Can you give the context, please. I see half a dozen solutions ranging from removing the first line of the csv with an editor to metadata injection.